# after edting bashrc, everything is gone except src

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have ubuntu 20.04 and i removed anaconda3 just like this website (https://technowikis.com/38827/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-ubuntu)
and then everything is gone in my ubuntu,
except gee_asset_manager file and src.
but my usr/bin contains things I owned. I do not know what to do. My bashrc is compeletly empty now. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you copy-paste commands from that webpage without modifications?

Especially `rm -rf ~ / anaconda3` command with spaces between symbols `~`  and `/`?

If you did, then you need to restore from backup, you removed your home directory.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot find my backup... and Can I do anything using my etc/bin files?

Comment: If you don't have backups then you need to `umount` the filesystem with your home directory or shut down your computer if the filesystem was the root and then start looking into file recovery options.